# Show irreducibility of polynomial representation of $SU(2)$

Tags: matrices, group-theory, polynomials, representation-theory, group-actions

I am looking at this exercise for 2 days and honestly cannot make any progress, so I really appreciate any help.

Let $V_n$ ⊆ $C[x_1, x_2]$ be the space of all homogeneous polynomials of degree
n. Let $Φ_n$: SU2 → $Aut_C(Vn)$ be a map given by

$Φ_n(A)$: $F(x_1, x_2)$ → $F(a_{1,1}x_1+a_{2,1}x_2, a_{1,2}x_1+a_{2,2}x_2)$,

$A$ = \begin{bmatrix}a_{1,1}&a_{1,2}\\a_{2,1}&a_{2,2}\end{bmatrix} ∈ SU2 .
Show that $Φ_n$ is irreducible for every n ∈ N.

Comment: In my opinion this is a duplicate of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4042702/11619). If there is something not addressed there, or you have trouble with some of the ideas/techniques there, can you specify? I want to leave this window ajar, just in case (I have a relevant dupehammer, so my vote would be immediately binding, and the rush feels unnecessary).

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you. In my exercise, there is a hint to "find subspaces which are $Φ_n|T$-invariant, where $T$ is the circle group consisting of diagonal matrices of $SU_2.$)." I went through the duplicate question, but couldn´t connect that with my question specificely.

Comment: Ok (+1). Then I give you a hint. Why is the span of a single monomial $x_1^ix_2^j$ $T$-invariant? Obviously $i+j=n$.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova - in Fulton/Harris book in the GTM series you find an elementary proof that for all $n\geq 1$ it follows $Sym^n(k^2)$ is an irreducible $SL(2,k)$-module ($k$ the complex number field). The complexification of $SU(2)$ is $SL(2,k)$ - maybe a "similar proof" applies to $SU(2)$. There are precise relations between $SU(2)$-modules and $SL(2,k)$-modules.

Comment: @TerezaTizkova - there is a book by Brian Hall in the GTM series where an elementary introduction to these topics is given. He discusses $SU(2),SU(3)$ in detail.